How can I modify a v5 pinescript code to compare daily ema crossover versus shorter timeframe ema crossover?
I'm trying to establish an area on my chart that indicates me when daily ema crossover happening while whatching a shorter timeframe (1h per example). I started with this code but it doesn't work. Any one of you having an idea ?
// Define moving averages
ema10 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

// Request daily timeframe data
[daily_ema10, daily_ema20] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [ema10, ema20])

// Define conditions
bullish_condition = ta.crossover(daily_ema10, daily_ema20) and ta.crossover(ema50, ema200)

// Plot the colored area
bgcolor(bullish_condition ? color.new(color.green, 80) : na)

